# How to fetch table with bytea type id column?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a PostgreSQL database and I want to fetch some data with Hibernate. I got an entity like;

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @Type(type = "uuid-binary")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "user-generator", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "user-generator")
    @Column(name = "user_id", length = 16, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID userId;


    ....

}
```

When I try to get all User values with Hibernate there is no problem. Hibernate maps UUID fields. But when I try to get a specific User with UUID it returns empty result. How can I fetch a single User with userId value?

```
List<User> users = userDao.getAll();  //I can get all users with non-empty userId fields
userDao.getWithId(users.get(0).getUserId())  // returns null.

users.get(0).getUserId()  //returns java.util.UUID instance like "33333-3333..."
```

**EDIT:**

```
public User getWithId(UUID Id) {
    EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
    try {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> typeRoot = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(typeRoot).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(typeRoot.get("userId"), Id));
        final Query query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
        return (User) JPAHelpers.getSingleResultOrNull(query);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `users.get(0).getUserId()` <-- what does this alone actually return?

Comment: What is the implementation of `getWithId()` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It would be returning a `UUID` as this field `private UUID userId;` suggests.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz We need the OP to verify what is happening.  Speculation won't solve this problem, most likely.

Comment: Yep, you're right.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Edited question.

Comment: @hellzone Can you please show the implementation of `getWithId()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Although, you didn't share the implementation of `getWithId()` method. I am assuming that you're using the JPA Repository methods. Try annotating the `UUID` field with:

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType")
```

or

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType") // if column is VARCHAR
```

Or try defining the `columnDefinition` parameter in `@Column` annotation:

```
@Column(name = "user_id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", unique = true, nullable = false)
```

Comment: Added getWithId method impl. I already got @Type(type = "uuid-binary") on userId field. Column type is "bytea" by the way.